# Django Admin: models not showing if the user is not a superuser

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I have a problem and seeks assistance and guide on this matter

I have 3 applications in my project that are called `frontend`, `file_maintenance`, and `reports`.

I am using only one `models` for each application and it is in `frontend`.

To use the `models` from the `frontend` to the other apps I imported the models like this in the other app's model `from frontend.models import *`.

And now to register the same model with different functionalities I used `proxy`.

Now the problem starts when the user is not a superuser, it only shows the model that I registered in `frontend` regardless of the permissions assigned.

I think my problem is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26135842/django-app-not-showing-in-admin-site-for-some-users) but I really can't understand it because I recently learned django

Sorry for my English and if my question does not provide enough information just let me know, thanks in advance.

I am using Django 1.8.2

Comment: What version of Django?

Comment: I am using Django 1.8.2

Comment: I think is related with this [ticket](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/11154), exists this [gist](https://gist.github.com/magopian/7543724) for a possible solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you may be running into an old bug in Django that does not allow Proxy models to show up in Django Admin. 
https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/11154

A work around is listed in here: https://gist.github.com/magopian/7543724

However, I am not sure what exactly you are trying to do from the description above.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So, does it have a workaround? (in a beginners perspective)

Comment: Not really - other than do not use Proxy model if you want to use the admin. What are you trying to do that you need to use Proxy model for ?

Comment: This answer fixed my issue (TabularInline not showing up) after 3 hours playing around...